# Lock-Bitlocker after Robocopy - access denied

Tags: robocopy, bitlocker

I'm trying to create a backup script that unlocks an external bitlocker drive, robocopies files to it, then locks it when it's done. I am able to unlock and copy just fine, but the final step of "Lock-Bitlocker" is giving me an "access denied" error because the drive is still in use (e.g. the robocopy is still wrapping up).

```
Unlock-Bitlocker e: -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString "omgClearText" -AsPlainText -Force)
Robocopy "\\MyFileServer\C$\Files" "E:\" /Bunch /of /parameters
Lock-Bitlocker e:
```

I've tried using **Wait-Job** to wait for Robocopy to complete, but that doesn't work. I've considered **Lock-Bitlocker E: -ForceDismount** but I don't want to dismount until after all files have successfully copied over.

Is there a way to properly wait for the system to copy before locking?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and could reproduce this problem.
What solved it for me was to insert

```
timeout 5
```

before the line with the lock command.

Comment: Oh my... After analyzing further, it seems it's not about wait time AT ALL. You will just need to add another line `lock-bitlocker e:` and that's all!